# Como criar e mostrar um condição através de uma variável no carrinho?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Seguinte, tenho uns problema para resolver no meu e-commerce, um desses problemas irei explicar logo abaixo:

Eu preciso criar a seguinte condição:

Hoje meu e-commerce tem uma variável que é aplicada a cada produto, essa variável é dias de produção, justamente para informar meu cliente que o produto será fabricado em x dias úteis.

Para executar tal variável utilizo o código abaixo:

```html
<?php
    // Insert a Custom Admin Field
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => 'days_manufacture',
        'label'             => __( 'Days for Manufacture', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'       => '',
        'description'       => __( 'Insert here', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'              => 'number',
        'custom_attributes' => array(
            'step'  => 'any',
            'min'   => '1'
        ),
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}


// Save the field
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){
$woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['days_manufacture'];
if( !empty( $woocommerce_number_field ) )
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'days_manufacture', esc_attr( $woocommerce_number_field ) );
}


// Store custom field
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_days_field', 10, 2 );

function save_days_field( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    $special_item = get_post_meta( $product_id , 'days_manufacture',true );
    if(!empty($special_item)) {
        $cart_item_data[ 'days_manufacture' ] = $special_item;

        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
        WC()->session->set( 'days_manufacture', $special_item );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Render meta on cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

function rendering_meta_field_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    // Woo 2.4.2 updates
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['days_manufacture'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( "name" => __( "Days", "woocommerce" ), "value" => $cart_item['days_manufacture'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
} ?>
```

Bom, até esse ponto tudo funcionando perfeitamente, no caso ele mostra no meu carrinho, em cada produto, o tempo de execução do mesmo. Agora que vem a minha dúvida, estou precisando inserir um campo, conforme a imagem abaixo, onde será mostrada o maior tempo de fabricação dentre os itens do carrinho,abaixo segue uma imagem demonstrando melhor minha necessidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lembrando que necessito somente inserir essa informação que se encontra em verde na imagem.

Grato a todos desde já!

Comment: resumindo você precisa saber onde mexer para inserir essa informação e como pegar os dos produtos para fazer o calculo é isso?

Comment: Quero somente que no carrinho seja mostrada, como na imagem, uma frase onde contenha a maior variável dentre os produtos do carrinho, no caso da imagem são 2 produtos, onde o produto "Elefante" tem 14 dias úteis é maior que a "Girafa"que são 10 dias úteis, sendo assim a frase será utilizando a variável com valor 14.

Comment: Cada produto não vai conter o tempo de confecção e somente que aparece o tempo maior de confecção no verde? E isso?

Answer (score 0):

Galera o problema foi resolvido, o código abaixo foi testado e aprovado!

Segue:

```html
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'days_of_manufacture');
function days_of_manufacture() {
        $day_txt = ' ' . __('day', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
        $days_txt = ' ' . __('days', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
        $text = __('Your Order will be produced in: ', 'your_theme_domain_slug' );
        $max_days = 0;

        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item )
            if($cart_item['days_manufacture'] > $max_days)
                $max_days = $cart_item['days_manufacture'];

        if($max_days != 0) {
            if ($max_days == 1)
                $days_txt = $day_txt;

            $output = $text . $max_days . $days_txt;
            echo "<div class='woocommerce-info'>$output</div>";
        }
}
```